# How do I make a reusable form component group with Redux-Form v6?

Tags: redux-form

I'm trying to make a reusable form component **group** (section?) for use with Redux-Form v6. Ideally I don't want it to be aware of *where* it is used within a form, so that I can use it anywhere within a form (at the root or nested). How can I do this?

For example, I have an `Address` component that uses Redux-Form's `Field` for address1, city, state, zip, etc, like this:

```
class Address extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Field
        component={MyReduxFormInput}
        name="address1" // <== How to name for generic case?
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Here's a simplified `MyReduxFormInput`:

```
module.exports = field => {
  return <input {...field.input} />
}
```

I'm creating a form where I need to collect the user's address, as well as multiple addresses from some professional references. So, I want to use `Address` once at the root and multiple times in a nested fashion. The trick is, I can't simply use `Address` as I've written it above, because while that will work for the root address, it won't work for nested situations. As shown in the [FieldArray example docs](http://redux-form.com/6.0.2/examples/fieldArrays/), the `name` supplied to `Field` needs to be `` name={`${member}.address1`} ``. But then that wouldn't work at the root.

One idea which just occurred to me is for the `Address` component to take a `member` argument, which would be blank at the root. I'll try that and report back. But I was thinking Redux-Form `Field` components would be automatically aware of their nesting level; they should look up their hierarchy and be able to know their necessary `name` prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea of my component taking a `member` prop (as in, a name prefix depending on the nesting) works great. Wish I would've thought of it many hours ago.

Here's what `Address` looks like:

```
class Address extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    member: PropTypes.string
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    member: ''
  }

  render() {
    const { member } = this.props
    const name = n => `${member}${n}`

    return (
      <Field
        component={MyReduxFormInput}
        name={name('address1')}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

And here's how it might be used:

```
const references = ({ fields }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      fields.map((member, index) => {
        return <Address member={member} key={index} />
      })
    </div>
  )
}

<Address />
<FieldArray name="professionalReferences" component={references} />
```

Comment: The hours I wasted trying to solve this involved traversing the hierarchy (using `React.Children` stuff) and dynamically modifying any use of `Field` by modifying its `name` argument to include the prefix. This worked but, because it's creating new components, gets buggy with the state such as when the user tries to click into a field (they'd have to click multiple times). But I wonder if one could instead simply look up the hierarchy, and whenever e.g. a `FieldArray` is found, use its name as the name prefix?